# Can faulty USB 3.0 device break USB 3.0 circuit in my computer?

Tags: usb, ethernet, damage, usb-hub

can a faulty USB 3.0 hub with Ethernet port break USB 3.0 circuit in a laptop so that only USB 2.0 in those USB 3.0 ports works after that? Consider no device connected to the USB hub, only Ethernet cable.

I have suspition that this could have happened to my laptop. So I don't know if it's safe to try plugging it again or to return this USB device.

Thank you.

Comment: Hypothetically yes, but highly unlikely.

Comment: Shove 5V into the SSTX+/- or SSRX+/- and it could quite easily fry the USB 3.x transceivers without damaging the USB2.0 transceiver. Badly designed plug or too much force could cause physical damage to the connector (broken pins) which could conceivably break USB3.x lines. Why do you think it has happened? As it stands your question is incredibly open ended.

Comment: That makes sense. Could have been broken pins as well. I have a new ThinkPad Yoga S3 laptop. I updated from Win 8 do Win 10. I plugged a brand new i-tec USB 3.0 hub with Ethernet adapter and installed drivers. Didn't work at all in one USB 3 port, mostly worked in another. So I returend the laptop. Service changed motherboard, saying it works. Plugged my i-tec again - same problem. I retured it again. Service changed motherboard again, saying it works. So I suspect this i-tec can be the root of my issues.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you did to USB3 port and how it is protected from inductive load transients.

Here are some fundamentals on [USB3](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/sales_and_marketing/presentation/product_presentation/4c/78/dc/cb/1d/47/4c/8d/usb_type-c_power_delivery_advanced_protection_fundamentals_pres_web.pdf/files/usb_type-c_power_delivery_advanced_protection_fundamentals_pres_web.pdf/_jcr_content/translations/en.usb_type-c_power_delivery_advanced_protection_fundamentals_pres_web.pdf) transient protection diodes.

The advice I read came from wirecutter.com

"The most important tips are to not kink the many cords in your setup and to gently connect devices and USB plugs to avoid bending the prongs in the USB ports. If the hub gets dusty or grimy, use compressed air to remove particles from the ports, and carefully wipe down the surface of the device with rubbing alcohol."